# How can I solve problem with vuex and unit-testing?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, mocha.js, vuex

I am trying to write and run unit-testing first time with mocha and faced some problem.
I have a component `Table.vue` wrote with vuetify

```
    <v-container>
        <h1>Table</h1>
        <v-layout
                text-center
                wrap
        >
            <v-simple-table v-if="table.length">
                <template v-slot:default>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-left">Id</th>
                        <th class="text-left">Name</th>
                        <th class="text-left">Description</th>
                        <th class="text-left">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="(item, index) in table" :key="index">
                        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <v-btn
                                    color="blue"
                                    :to="{name: 'create', params: { item: item, id: item.id }}"
                            >
                                Update
                            </v-btn>
                            <v-btn
                                    color="red"
                                    @click="show(item)"
                            >
                                Delete
                            </v-btn>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </template>
            </v-simple-table>
        </v-layout>
        <v-btn
                :to="{name: 'create'}"
                color="primary"
        >
            <span class="mr-2">Create</span>
        </v-btn>
        <modal name="hello-world">
            <v-container>
                <v-layout
                        text-center
                        wrap
                >
                    Are you sure you eant to remove this item?
                </v-layout>
                <v-layout
                        text-center
                        wrap
                >
                    <v-btn
                            color="red"
                            @click="deleteItem"
                    >
                        Yes
                    </v-btn>
                    <v-btn
                            color="primary"
                            @click="hide"
                    >
                        No
                    </v-btn>
                </v-layout>
            </v-container>
        </modal>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
    import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'
    export default {
        name: "Table",
        data() {
            return {
                itemToRemove: null
            }
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapActions([
                'removeItem'
            ]),
            show (item) {
                this.$modal.show('hello-world');
                this.itemToRemove = item
            },
            hide () {
                this.$modal.hide('hello-world');
                this.itemToRemove = null
            },
            deleteItem () {
                this.removeItem(this.itemToRemove)
                this.hide()
            }
        },
        computed:
            mapState({
            table: state => state.table.table
        })
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

And I want to run test there. I have file `table.spec.js` inside `tests/unit` folder

```
import { expect } from 'chai'
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Table from '@/components/Table.vue'
const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Vuex)
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {}
})

describe('Table.vue', () => {
    it('renders h1 tag', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Table, {localVue, store})
    expect(wrapper.find('h1').text().equal('Table'))
})
})
```

When I run command `npm run test:unit` I have error `1) Table.vue
       renders h1 tag:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'table' of undefined`
previously it was error with text `Cannot read property 'state' of undefined`

I tried to include vuex inside tests, but it is my first time with unit-test and looks like I do something wrong

I need my test to be passed and maybe someone can help me to write new test for some event, for example click button and call action. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You got to read through https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/using-with-vuex.html

They have great examples of mocking vuex, which is what you need to do. It looks like this:

```
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Actions from '../../../src/components/Actions'

const localVue = createLocalVue()

localVue.use(Vuex)

describe('Actions.vue', () => {
  let actions
  let store

  beforeEach(() => {
    actions = {
      actionClick: jest.fn(),
      actionInput: jest.fn()
    }
    store = new Vuex.Store({
      actions
    })
  })

  it('dispatches "actionInput" when input event value is "input"', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Actions, { store, localVue })
    const input = wrapper.find('input')
    input.element.value = 'input'
    input.trigger('input')
    expect(actions.actionInput).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
```

Comment: How can I replace this with mocha? actionClick: jest.fn(),
      actionInput: jest.fn()

Comment: I believe a lot of people use the `spy()` method from `sinon` when they're working with Mocha in order to mock functions. It's a whole different library.